# javafx.fxml.LoadException when loading FXML file online

Tags: javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I'm working on a JavaFX application, in this application I load the fxml file from my webserver but i keep getting an error.
How can i resolve this error?

The FXML source:
http://fryslanscripts.net63.net/cache/Fighter/fighter.fxml

Error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/cache/Fighter/fighter.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2403)
at j.start(FighterFXUI.java:32)
at J.run(FighterFXUI.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$59/542475950.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$58/481059372.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$50/2063016732.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at D.initialize(FighterController.java:52)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
... 14 more
```

I'm using this code to start the Application:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class FighterFXUI extends Application {

public static Stage stage;

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) {
    try {
        LogUtil.append("Setting Stage.");
        this.stage = stage;
        LogUtil.append("Setting FXML Loader.");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        LogUtil.append("Setting Controller.");
        loader.setController(new FighterController());
        LogUtil.append("Setting FXML File.");
        loader.setLocation(new URL("http://fryslanscripts.net63.net/cache/Fighter/fighter.fxml"));
        LogUtil.append("Loading Scene.");
        Parent page = (Parent) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        LogUtil.append("Setting Stylesheet.");
        scene.getStylesheets().add("http://fryslanscripts.net63.net/cache/Fighter/fighter.css");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        LogUtil.append("Showing Stage.");
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.show();
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.append(LogUtil.getStackTrace(e));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main() {
    LogUtil.append("Loading FX Toolkit.");
    new JFXPanel();

    LogUtil.append("Loading UI.");
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
            new FighterFXUI().start(new Stage());
        }
    });
}
}
```

This Is The FighterController class

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import org.rev317.min.api.methods.Game;
import org.rev317.min.api.methods.Players;
import org.rev317.min.api.wrappers.Tile;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class FighterController implements Initializable {

@FXML
TextField customNpcTextField, safespotTextField, specialAttackID, regularAttackID, foodIDTextField,
        minHealthTextField, customLootTextField, maxLootDistanceTextField, searchNpcTextField, searchItemTextField;

@FXML
Slider specialAttackPercentSlider;

@FXML
CheckBox burryBonesCheckBox, quickPrayersCheckBox, addCoinsToMoneyPouchCheckBox, eatToMakeSpaceForLootCheckBox,
        FoodLobsterCheckBox, FoodMonkfishCheckBox, FoodSharkCheckBox, FoodCaveFishCheckBox, FoodMantaRayCheckBox,
        FoodRockTailCheckBox;

@FXML
Button startButton, setSafeSpotButton, findMonsterByNameButton, addNpcButton, removeNpcButton,addLootButton,removeLootButton;

@FXML
TextArea updateLogTextArea;

@FXML
ListView cachedNpcsList, savedNpcsList,cachedItemsList,savedItemsList;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            try {
                LogUtil.append("Setting ArrayLists.");
                if (FryslanFighter.itemCache == null) {
                    FryslanFighter.itemCache = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                if (FryslanFighter.npcCache == null) {
                    FryslanFighter.npcCache = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                if( FryslanFighter.ids == null){
                    FryslanFighter.ids = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                if( FryslanFighter.loot == null){
                    FryslanFighter.loot = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                if( FryslanFighter.food == null){
                    FryslanFighter.food = new ArrayList<>();
                }

                //Add Npcs
                LogUtil.append("Adding NPC's.");
                String npcIds = customNpcTextField.getText().trim();
                if(!customNpcTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    if(npcIds != null) {
                        for (String id : npcIds.split(",")) {
                            FryslanFighter.ids.add(Integer.parseInt(id));
                        }
                    }
                }

                ObservableList npcs = savedNpcsList.getItems();
                if(npcs.size() > 0){
                    for(Object npc : npcs){
                        FryslanFighter.ids.add(Integer.parseInt(npc.toString().split(" - ")[0]));
                    }
                }

                //Add Loot
                LogUtil.append("Adding Loot.");
                String lootIds = customLootTextField.getText().trim();
                if(!customLootTextField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    for (String id : lootIds.split(",")) {
                        FryslanFighter.loot.add(Integer.parseInt(id) - 1);
                    }
                }

                ObservableList loots = savedItemsList.getItems();
                if(loots.size() > 0){
                    for(Object loot : loots){
                        FryslanFighter.loot.add(Integer.parseInt(loot.toString().split(" - ")[0]));
                    }
                }

                LogUtil.append("Adding Textfield data.");
                FryslanFighter.specialAttackWeaponId = Integer.parseInt(specialAttackID.getText());
                FryslanFighter.regularAttackWeaponId = Integer.parseInt(regularAttackID.getText());
                FryslanFighter.food.add(Integer.parseInt(foodIDTextField.getText()));
                FryslanFighter.minHP = Integer.parseInt(minHealthTextField.getText());
                FryslanFighter.distanceToLoot = Integer.parseInt(maxLootDistanceTextField.getText());
                FryslanFighter.specialAttackEnergy = (int) specialAttackPercentSlider.getValue();
                System.out.println((int) specialAttackPercentSlider.getValue());

                LogUtil.append("Adding CheckBox data.");
                FryslanFighter.burryBones = burryBonesCheckBox.isSelected();
                FryslanFighter.useQuickPrayers = quickPrayersCheckBox.isSelected();
                FryslanFighter.addCoinsToMoneyPouch = addCoinsToMoneyPouchCheckBox.isSelected();
                FryslanFighter.eatToMakeSpaceForLoot = eatToMakeSpaceForLootCheckBox.isSelected();

                if (FoodLobsterCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                    FryslanFighter.food.add(380);
                }

                if (FoodMonkfishCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                    FryslanFighter.food.add(7947);
                }

                if (FoodSharkCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                    FryslanFighter.food.add(386);
                }

                if (FoodCaveFishCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                    FryslanFighter.food.add(15267);
                }

                if (FoodMantaRayCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                    FryslanFighter.food.add(392);
                }

                if (FoodRockTailCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                    FryslanFighter.food.add(15273);
                }

                LogUtil.append("Handling UI Closing.");
                Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
                if(FighterFXUI.stage != null) {
                    FighterFXUI.stage.close();
                }
                LogUtil.append("Setting loaded variable to True.");
                FryslanFighter.loaded = true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                LogUtil.append(LogUtil.getStackTrace(e) + "\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the actual code that's generating the exception? The stack trace says the `NullPointerException` is generated at line 52 of `FighterController`.

Comment: @James_D this is line 52: `startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {`

Comment: So `startButton` is `null`. If you want more help, you really need to edit your question to include enough code to diagnose the problem. Please post at least enough of the controller to show the declaration of the variable that's `null`, and the FXML that defines it (assuming it's `@FXML`-injected).

Comment: @James_D Done could you please take a look?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there. I guess you should make sure you have deployed the latest version of your FXML file. You could do some logging with `loader.getNamespace().keySet().forEach(LogUtil::append);` after loading the FXML (comment out the body of the `initialize` method to suppress the error). This will show all the `fx:id`s that are recognized by the `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: @James_D I found the problem, it was due to Obfuscation of the Controller class upon uploading wich changed the variable names.